# Angular 2 get classnames as input from host and apply to child element

Tags: angular

What's the best way to get a string of class names in an Angular 2 component and add it to its child? I would also like to detect if the string is empty or if the option is not used and not add the class.

My Component looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-dropdown-toggle",
    template: `
        <button <Input Class from the _classname variable here>>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
            <i class="fa fa-arrow"></i>
        </button>
    `,
    host: {
        "[class.dropdown-toggle]" : "true"
    }
})
export class MyDropdownToggle {
  @Input() _classname: string;
  ...
}
```

And I would like to use it like this:

```
<my-dropdown-toggle [_classname]="btn btn-danger">Hello</my-dropdown-toggle>
```